# Python linked list: how to access the next value?

Tags: python, linked-list

Here's my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo=None, next=None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None

# then I declare a list and a node
S = LinkedList()
cel = Node
cel = S.first
```

Now I want to put something in the list:

```
  n = 0
  x = 0
  while n < 5:
      x = input()
      cel.val = x
      cel = cel.next
```

Yet I get an error stating that:

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You didn't state any variable called "val" nor stated any variable/integer to next so it will return None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cel` is equal to `S.first`. `S.first` is equal to `None`. 
When you try to get `val` from `cel`m you try to get `val` attribute of `None`.

And none of you classes has `val` attribute... So it is possible to assign it, but I'd suggest to avoid it, because it is not clear to create it somewhere without declaring it in class itself.